# Script to change registry entries in Windows 7 from IDE to AHCI in the recovery partition

Tags: windows, batch-file, ide, recovery, cloning

I've gotten a bit stumped by this problem and have asked some other co-workers and other IT friends about this, we've tried all we can think of but can't seem to get it working.

Here's the long of the situation for context ***I'll abbreviate the question below***, I have a Windows 7 x64 VM running on Server 2012's HyperV.  Window's 7 can only be used as a Generation 1 VM.  Generation 1 VM's do not support AHCI, only IDE so I have to change my physical disks from AHCI to IDE every time, I'm trying to script it so that others in the office can easily prep machines.  I am cloning the .vhd to a physical disk for machine deployment, I'm keeping the VM up to date with Windows Updates so that I'm not sitting for half an hour waiting on them to download then install.  I let it run all the time and reboot it every once in awhile.  When I want to clone I shut it down, clone it's VHD using VHD2Disk and spin up the disk in a new machine.  We install Dell's so they are OEM keys and all use the same product key.  After I place the cloned disk in the new machine I sysprep it so that I am able to enter a new license key.  There may be better ways to do this but this works very well for me right now.

After I clone the .vhd to physical disk, slap it in a dell machine it will BSOD the first time since Windows is set to load in IDE and the machine is set to load an AHCI disk.  A registry change is needed.  After the BSOD I am able to boot into the recovery partition.  From there I launch RegEdit from command prompt, load the System hive and change these two keys

```
HKLM\OfflineSYS\ControlSet001\services\intelide\Start from 00000000 to 00000003
HKLM\OfflineSYS\ControlSet001\services\msahci\Start from 00000003 to 00000000
```

then reboot and it loads in AHCI and everything is happy as can be.

Now on to the question, how do I script it? I've tried a bunch of different methods and so far this has been the most promising.  Create a batch file that states this *Note: the Ping's are my "wait" as I can't seem to get wait to work in the recovery partition*

```
reg.exe load HKLM\OfflineSYS C:\Windows\System32\Config\System
ping 127.0.0.1
IntelIDE.REG
ping 127.0.0.1
MSAHCI.REG
ping 127.0.0.1
reg.exe unload HKLM\OfflineSYS
```

The IntelIDE.REG looks like this

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKLM\OfflineSYS\ControlSet001\services\intelide]
"Start"=dword:00000003
```

And the MSAHCI.REG looks like this

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKLM\OfflineSYS\ControlSet001\services\msahci]
"Start"=dword:00000000
```

I've tried running my .bat as administrator and it asks if I want to merge my changed with the registry and I hit OK each time, however the changes never seem to apply. **This works 100% of the time when using the REGEdit GUI**

I have also tried using a command like this in place of the .reg files, also didn't work.

```
reg add "HKLM\OfflineSYS\ControlSet001\Services\intelide\Start" /f /v "Start" /t REG_DWORD /d 00000003
reg add "HKLM\OfflineSYS\ControlSet001\Services\msahci\Start" /f /v "Start" /t REG_DWORD /d 00000000
```

Any thoughts anyone has would be much appreciated, hope I stump a few of you but not everyone!

Comment: Most likely your registry writes are getting redirected to the 32 bit area of the registry. Have you tried using REG ADD? I don't have a 64 bit machine in front of me now. Try doing REG ADD /? on a 64 bit OS and you will get some clues. You should be able to specify 32/64 bit area of registry.

Comment: I have tried REG ADD but I never even considered it could be going to the 32bit area.  It is a 64bit OS.  I'll take a look into that.  The strange thing to me is manually making those changes in the REGEDIT gui works every time.  But it's possible it's going to the wrong place.

Comment: **Edit** looking further into it the 32bit sections on a 64bit machine don't seem to be applicable in this instance.  From what I read it seems to apply more specifically to software not system.  Running an REG ADD/? I don't have a 64 or 32bit option available.

Comment: **Update** I think I found the problem!  When making the registry edit using my .REG files I need to specify the fully written out "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" instead of using the shortcut HKLM.  No idea why that made a difference but that appears to have fixed it.  I've already applied the changes to all the computers I was working on so I can't get a real world test until we need to order more machines but I'm hopeful!